# JPA in JBoss - Hibernate custom field type configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jasypt

I'm using annotation based entities. I want to use the jasypt encryption datatypes.

I cannot find anything that clearly indicates how to configure them. My persistance.xml just has references to a datasource - no hibernate specific configs.

Is there any documentation out there on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

first, define the encryption type with a
@TypeDef annotation, which could be either inside the persisted entity
class or inside a @TypeDefs declaration in a separate
package-info.java file:

```
@TypeDef(
    name="encryptedString", 
    typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class, 
    parameters= {
        @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName", value="myHibernateStringEncryptor")
    }
)
```

...and then simply map  property with the already declared type:

```
   @Type(type="encryptedString")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
```

Providing the encryptor to Hibernate
myHibernateStringEncryptor ,This can be binded in two different manners, depending on whether we are using an IoC container like Spring or not.

With Spring

```
    <bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
        class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="registeredName">
            <value>strongHibernateStringEncryptor</value>
        </property>
        <property name="algorithm">
            <value>PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
        <value>jasypt</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Without Spring,

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
  HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =
      HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
  registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("strongHibernateStringEncryptor", strongEncryptor);
```

[Documentation here](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html)

Comment: how do I register myHibernateStringEncryptor with hibernate in the enterprise container?

Comment: have edited the answer to include that, you can also refer the documentation